# Связь между объектом приложения и виджетами

Tags: qt, c++

В примере "Hello world" - есть те 2 строки в методе main:

```
1. QApplication app(p, v);
2. QPushButton btn("Hello", NULL);
```

Почему нету связи между объектом приложения и объектом кнопки? Т.е. приложение не обязано знать о существовании её виджетов?

Я как человек пришедший из .NET-a не понимаю сего момента.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Связь, безусловно, есть. Объекту [QApplication](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QApplication.html) известны виджеты, формирующие GUI, в частности, окна:

> It knows about the application's windows. You can ask which widget is at a certain position using widgetAt(), get a list of topLevelWidgets() and closeAllWindows(), etc.

Вы также можете получить список всех виджетов, вызвав метод allWidgets().

Посмотрим, как объект приложения "узнаёт" о существовании виджетов. Собственно объект QApplication должен существовать в единственном экземпляре для любого графического приложения. При этом объект приложения доступен глобально, например, через [макрос qApp](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#qApp):

> A global pointer referring to the unique application object. It is equivalent to the pointer returned by the QCoreApplication::instance() function except that, in GUI applications, it is a pointer to a QApplication instance. Only one application object can be created.

Используя макрос qApp или другой способ добраться до объекта приложения, каждый виджет "регистрируется" в приложении при вызове конструктора.

Кстати, по поводу окон. Новичков в Qt в примере "Hello World" обычно смущает скорее отсутствие кода создания окна и добавления в него как в контейнер виджета (в Вашем случае кнопки). В Qt [любой виджет, не имеющий окна, становится окном](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-tutorial.html):

> Each GUI component (e.g. buttons, labels, text editor) is a widget that is placed somewhere within a user interface window, or is displayed as an independent window.

Об этом написано также [в описании конструктора QWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwidget.html#QWidget):

> Constructs a widget which is a child of parent. If parent is 0, the new widget becomes a window. If parent is another widget, this widget becomes a child window inside parent.

Comment: т.е. другими словами главные виджеты известны классу приложения через макросы либо через конструктор, так?